Policy change proposal: Minor OpSec edits
Right now the official policy for accepting and rejecting sub-2k user edits includes the following statement:

Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.

... List of common edit reasons ...


(emphasis mine)
So clearly, an edit that just HTTPS'es links is not allowed by this policy.
As we are Cryptography.SE I think we should lead by example when it comes to operational security and this means I want to add the following exception allowing (formally) the approval of edits that just HTTPS'ify links.
I want to add an additional point in the list of common edit reasons stating:


To increase the operational security of the post and especially convert HTTP to HTTPS links if possible and non-breaking.


(and if we can't add it, this post shall be considered an ammendment to the help center)

So how does this work?

You upvote this post to show your support for this idea.
You downvote if you don't want to see this idea becoming a "hard" community policy.
As soon and as long as this post has +6 votes, this sort of edits shall be approved.
The earliest point at which this post becomes authoritative is May 15th 2016 (two weeks from now).


Assuming that this proposal does achieve a reasonable consensus, we should probably ask for an exception to the hard six character minimum edit length rule enforced by the Stack Exchange software. (We might not get one, of course, but asking wouldn't hurt.)
